# Is there a way to add alt text to an img tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, alt

There is an img tag being placed on a hidden portion of my wordpress site through some java script. Everytime I run a scan on my site looking for accessibility errors, this pulls up on every page of every site. I was wondering if there is a way to add an alt tag to it saying "this is empty" or anything really, since it's impossible to reach or see anyway.

I have tried looking at other alternatives, but I haven't had any luck so far, so any help would be greatly appreciated. The good thing is it seems to have a class name attached so hopefully that helps.

```
<div class="className">
     <img>
  <div>
  </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need:

```
$('img').attr('alt', 'Whatever you want');
```

or if you need it based on the class name in your example:

```
$('.className > img').attr('alt', 'Whatever you want');
```

Comment: This is what I have tried, and I haven't had any luck with it working. Is it possible that it's because it's something that's added through a script?

Comment: No. How is this not working? Which one did you try? How did you check it to say it doesn't work? etc.

Comment: I added the snippet to the JS code section on my site, and then I ran the accessibility checker again after clearing out my browser data to ensure the site is pulling the most updated info, and it's still not showing a tag. I tried both options with no luck. I'm not super experienced when it comes to this though, so any other suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which "js code section"? Update your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code I provided should be added to a document ready function.

Comment: It is possible that some JS is creating that empty img tag and appending it to your site. Therefore your selector will not have that particular img tag available when it runs and changes the alt tag.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about. At the moment I was trying a different snippet of code that was suggested below. https://imgur.com/v5IaDaG

Comment: What Lapskaus is saying is exactly what I think is happening. Because this isn't something you can even see in the source code when inspecting the page. It's put on the page through JS, and isn't visible in any part of the site.

Comment: Do you need that image at all? You said it is in a "hidden portion" of your website. If not then you should look into your WP code and modules to see where this comes from and fix that part instead of trying to find workarounds like these...

Comment: That's thee problem, is I've tried finding it, but haven't been able to track it down. It seems to be part of something else that I'm honestly not sure if the site needs or not. I figured this would be an easy work around initially so it seemed like the better option. I'll look further into what it actually is though.

Comment: Finding the root of the issue is IMO a better approach than trying to work around it. If a contributed WP module is creating that image, they should fix their code so that the image has an ALT tag. Or you may submit a fix, or fix it by yourself. If that image is not needed then why is it there at all? Maybe you have un unwanted module turned on. Many possibilities but it's all guessing since we don't know much about it.

Comment: I believe I have figured out what it is. I think it's a plugin that's built into WPBakery Builder, which is what the site is composed with. I believe it's an item called PhotoBox, and it's an overlay put on the page and it has to deal with uploading images. I'm mostly putting this here just in case anyone is having this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can always add attribute to an image using jquery, do it like this

```
$('img').attr('alt', 'This is very nice image');
```

If your image have a class than you can use

```
$('.class_name').attr('alt', 'This is very nice image');
```

If your image have a ID than you can use

```
$('#id_name').attr('alt', 'This is very nice image');
```

Answer (score 0):

With this script you can set a default alt tag for all images that have a falsy alt tag (no alt tag, empty string, etc).

Important to note is that alt tags have a reason. People who use a text oriented browser (like blind people) use those alt tag so they at least know what kind of image there is. It is also used by some browsers when an image can't be loaded. So make sure all images without an alt tag (in your jQuery selection) are always hidden if you want a default alt tag otherwise it could be annoying.

```js
$('img').filter(function() {
  return !this.alt;
}).attr('alt', 'this is empty');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="className">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.png&text=test">
  <img alt="" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.png&text=test2">
  <img alt="has alt" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.png&text=test3">
</div>
```